# Two label align vertically in tableView cell auto resizing swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

Try to auto resizing two labels align vertically within a cell, is that possible?

In the `storyboard`, we have to set `autolayout`, since I want to auto resizing two labels(one is on top of another).

I can't set each height so that the storyboard doesn't know what is the height of these two labels so it shows an error for `autolayout`.

[image]

if I click "Add Missing Constraints" button it will add a height for "subtitle"

or I can set height for "title" rather than "subtitle",

or make "title" equal to "subtitle" it will still accept.

[image]

here is the result:

[image]

A workaround will be separate these two to a different cell.
Any better solution? or am I just simply forget to do anything?

P.S. I'm using Xcode 8 with iOS 10.3.

Comment: you can set height and make it >=.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting out Proper constraints for both the labels-:

**Storyboard-:**

Constraints for first `label`-:

[image]

Constraints for second `label`-:

[image]

**Controller class(use Automatic Dimensions for `table view`)-:**

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    var dataForTableView:[ProductImage]?

    @IBOutlet weak var secondTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        secondTable.estimatedRowHeight = 96
        secondTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        // CHECK FOR DATA

        //print(dataForTableView?[0].url as Any)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}

extension ViewController1 : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1") as! testingCell2
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue;
        cell.secondLabel.text = "agfhjsgfhjsgdshgfhjsfjhvhssajs hjfbvhjfbvjhfgafgfhlgkaghkfakfhkflbvhfbvhfvbhfv ah fvfhbvfjhvbfhdavhfvhv"
        return cell
    }

    // Number of sections in table

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }// Default is 1 if not implemented

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

}
```

**Output-:**

[image]

I hope that is what you looking for, let me know if any issues.Thanks